# Can js-beautify be configured to avoid line breaking?

Tags: javascript, js-beautify

This line is breaked by js-beautify into multiple lines. Is it possible to prevent that? (using JsFormat Sublime Text plugin, or command-line)

I tried all options from http://jsbeautifier.org/

```
if(err) return new ApiError({ innerError: err }).respond(this.res);
```

becomes

```
if (err) return new ApiError({
  innerError: err
}).respond(this.res);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'transformed'? JSHint shouldn't be changing anything - it just reads the file and doesn't write anything. Do you mean it complains about the formatting? If so, I don't get any warnings when pasting your first line into the editor at http://jshint.com/

Comment: sorry it was JsFormat (js-beautify). JSHint only hints yes!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JsFormat rule for newline in es6 imports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765418/jsformat-rule-for-newline-in-es6-imports)