# JsFormat rule for newline in es6 imports

Tags: sublimetext3, js-beautify

JsFormat for Sublime Text 3 conforms to most ES6 standards, however, when auto-formatting import statements, it adds a new line to object imports. Here is what the pre-formatted line looks like:

```
import {func1, func2, func3} from 'some-module';
```

When auto-formatting, it turns into:

```
import {
    func1, func2, func3
}
from 'some-module';
```

Is there a way to disable this kind of formatting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the Github repo](https://github.com/jdc0589/JsFormat), JsFormat uses [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) to do the formatting. *That* project has [an open issue](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/382) where folks complain about various formatting issues, one of them being this very thing. There's a mildly long comment thread which ends in "Pull requests welcome", so unfortunately it looks like there is currently no way to disable this kind of formatting.

Comment: The issue referenced has been closed. 
A recent version for the beautifier added `preserve-inline` as an option for `brace-style`.

Comment: You have to provide a modifier before it according to the [README](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/blob/f9060f0755fdc64aadd78f55e505e5b0f0c1cc66/README.md#options): `[collapse|expand|end-expand|none][,preserve-inline]`

Answer (score 4):

On http://jsbeautifier.org/, there is check box to enable this setting: "Preserve inline braces/code blocks".

[image]

This feature was added in recent version for the beautifier as the `preserve-inline` option for `brace-style`.  This will keep inline (all on the same line) brace blocks unchanged.  It works as a modifier for the base setting (for example, `brace-style: "collapse,preserve-inline"`).