# How to stop new lines when formatting code

Tags: visual-studio-code

**EDIT: It is Beautify that is adding the new lines.** Not sure which rule though.

Is there a way to stop parameter lists and import lists from adding new lines per each list item when formatting code with?

E.g stop this:

```
function view(state$) {
  return state$.map(({weight,height,bmi}) =>
    div([
      renderWeightSlider(weight),
      renderHeightSlider(height),
      h2('BMI is ' + bmi)
    ])
  );
}
```

from becoming this:

```
function view(state$) {
  return state$.map(({
      weight,
      height,
      bmi
    }) =>
    div([
      renderWeightSlider(weight),
      renderHeightSlider(height),
      h2('BMI is ' + bmi)
    ])
  );
}
```

When right-clicking and selecting "format document"?

It also does it with imports like so:

```
import {
  makeDOMDriver,
  h1,
  a
} from '@cycle/dom';
```

However it is unwanted.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe brace-style ???  Try the alternatives : https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify/blob/master/Settings.md

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JsFormat rule for newline in es6 imports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765418/jsformat-rule-for-newline-in-es6-imports)

Comment: how did you solve the problem?

Comment: for me it was the extension prettier.js

Comment: Facing the same problem with CSS files. Formatting (CTRL + K D) CSS adds extra line below all the comments. Not sure whether it is default behavior or its because of Beautify.

Comment: Yep, "prettier" is the culprit, "print width" default value was set to 80.

Answer (score 12):

create or edit `.jsbeautifyrc` file in your root from you vscode project and put in to the file this json property

```json
{
    "brace_style": "collapse,preserve-inline"
}
```

this will also prevent to format all JavaScript object

Answer (score 1):

Include `"brace_style": "collapse,preserve-inline"` as Yitzchak said inside the .json settings file located here:

```
C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json
```

Answer (score 0):

**2021 Update for Eze_82's answer:**

Instead of just `"brace_style": "collapse,preserve-inline"`, you now need to include the following in the `settings.json` file of VSCode:

```json
"beautify.config": {
    "brace_style": "collapse,preserve-inline"
}
```

The location of the `settings.json` is still the same.